# slow performance since chrome 12

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, google-chrome

The last week when I was on chrome 11 yet, my website run perfectly. Yesterday when I did the new Chrome12 update I noticed that my website was much slower, almost unusable…

Here it is : http://emilevictorportenart.be/

The associated jquery file is :

```
    // copyright Portenart Emile-Victor
if ( (screen.width < 1024) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || ($.browser.msie) ) {
    document.location = "mobile/";
}

;$(document).ready(function(){
    //add keyboard span and hide it on the first screen
    $('section#content').append('<span class="keyboardUse"><span>MAJ: plus d\'infos<br /> ←→/QD/WA: changer de projet<br /> ↑↓/ZS: changer d\'image</span></span>');

    // caching DOM
    var $keyboardUse = $('.keyboardUse');
    var $headerNavUl = $('header nav ul');
    var $navMainBottom = $('.navMainBottom');
    var $headerNavSpanRelMore = $('header nav span[rel=more]');
    var $headerNavA_Arrow = $('header nav a, .arrow');
    var keyboardUseShowFirst = 0;
    var clickLinkAllow = 1;
    var $header = $('header');

    $keyboardUse.hide();

    // links
    $('a[rel=external]').live('click', function() {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });


    // height navigation Background pattern
    $navMainBottom.height(1000).css('top','-723px');
    $header.find('h1 a').css('margin-top','65px');

    // ul navigation slide when hover (1st time) & click next 
    $headerNavUl.hide();

    $headerNavSpanRelMore.one('mouseover', function(){
        $headerNavUl.slideDown(200);
        $navMainBottom.animate({'top':'-800px'},200);
        $(this).addClass('moreRotated');
    }); 

    $headerNavSpanRelMore.click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('moreRotated');

        if($headerNavUl.is(':visible')){
            $navMainBottom.animate({'top':'-723px'},200);
        } else {
            $navMainBottom.animate({'top':'-800px'},200);
        }

        $headerNavUl.slideToggle(200);
    });


    // leave project animation
    $('header nav a, .arrow').live('click', function(){

        if(clickLinkAllow === 1){
            $('section h1').css('z-index','-1').animate({'left':'-1000px'/* , 'top':'2000px' */},800);
            $('article').css('z-index','-1').animate({'left':'-965px', 'top':'2000px', 'opacity':'0'}, 750);
            $('.arrow').fadeOut(300);
            $('header h1').animate({'left':'0', 'opacity': '1'}, 700);

            var $keyboardUse = $('.keyboardUse');

            if(keyboardUseShowFirst === 0){
                $keyboardUse.addClass('full').fadeIn(200);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $keyboardUse.removeClass('full');
                }, 10000);

                keyboardUseShowFirst = 1;
            } else {
                $keyboardUse.show();
            }
        }

    });


    // caption
    $('article span[rel=more]').live('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('moreRotated');
        $('article .description').slideToggle(200);
    });


    // keyboard
        //stop keyboard action when input/textarea are on focus
    var inputTextareaFocus = 0;
    $('input, textarea').live('focus', function(){
        inputTextareaFocus = 1;
    });
    $('input, textarea').live('blur', function(){
        inputTextareaFocus = 0;
    });

    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
        if(inputTextareaFocus === 0){
            if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 81) { //left -- q
                $('header nav ul a[rel=active]').parent().prev().find('a').click();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) { //right -- d
                $('header nav ul a[rel=active]').parent().next().find('a').click();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 90) { //top -- 90
                $('.naviSquare li[rel=active]').prev().find('a').click();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) { //down --
                $('.naviSquare li[rel=active]').next().find('a').click();
            } else if (event.keyCode == 16) { //caps (maj)
                $('.naviSquare li:eq(0) a').click();
                $('article span[rel=more]').click();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }); 


    // projeft change

    //hide description and start waypoint
    function afterload(timeToLoadWaypoint){
        var $description = $('.description');
        $description.hide();

        setTimeout(function(){
            var idliNavisquare = 0;
            $('article figure img').waypoint(function(event, direction){
                if (direction === 'down') {
                    idliNavisquare++;
                }
                else {
                    idliNavisquare--;
                }

                var $naviSquareLi = $('.naviSquare li');
                $naviSquareLi.removeAttr('rel');
                $naviSquareLi.eq(idliNavisquare).attr('rel','active');
            });
            $('body').css({'overflow-y':'scroll', 'overflow-x':'auto'});

            //numbers of pictures and add squares
            var $articleFigureUlLi = $('article figure ul li');
            var nombreCreationLi = $articleFigureUlLi.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < nombreCreationLi; i++) {
                $articleFigureUlLi.eq(i).attr('id','crea'+i);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < nombreCreationLi; i++) {
                var tHeightImg4NaviSquare = $('figure li:eq('+i+') img').height();
                var tailleHeightNaviSquareFinal = parseInt((tHeightImg4NaviSquare / 700)*10, 10);
                var $ulNaviSquare = $('ul.naviSquare');

                if(i === 0){
                    $ulNaviSquare.append('<li rel="active"><a href="#content" style="height:'+ tailleHeightNaviSquareFinal +'px;"></li>');
                } else {
                    $ulNaviSquare.append('<li><a href="#crea'+i+'" style="height:'+ tailleHeightNaviSquareFinal +'px;"></a></li>');
                }

            }

            //allow localscroll on this links
            $('ul.naviSquare, .description').localScroll();
            $('.arrow').fadeIn(100);

            //add links on arrows
            var hrefPrevious = $('header nav ul a[rel=active]').parent().prev().find('a').attr('href');
            var hrefNext = $('header nav ul a[rel=active]').parent().next().find('a').attr('href');
            $('a[rel=prev]').attr('href', hrefPrevious);
            $('a[rel=next]').attr('href', hrefNext);

            //add share links
            var linkPageActive = 'http://emilevictorportenart.be/%23'+window.location.hash.substr(1);
            var titrePageActive = $('article h2').text();
            titrePageActive = titrePageActive+' from Emile-Victor Portenart Website';
            var descriptionPageActive = $('article .description p:eq(0)').text();
            descriptionPageActive = descriptionPageActive+' '

            var twitterShareLink = 'http://twitter.com/share?url='+linkPageActive+'&via=portenartev&text='+titrePageActive;
            var facebookShareLink = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+linkPageActive+'&t='+titrePageActive;
            var gmailShareLink = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&su='+titrePageActive+'&body='+linkPageActive;
            $('a.share.twitter').attr('href',twitterShareLink);
            $('a.share.facebook').attr('href',facebookShareLink);
            $('a.share.gmail').attr('href',gmailShareLink);

            clickLinkAllow = 1;

            //contact from http://tutorialblog.org/how-to-create-your-own-ajax-contact-form/
            $('#contactForm').submit( function(){

                //hide the form
                $('#contactForm').hide();

                //show the loading bar
                $('aside').append('<span class="loadingBar">loading...</span>'); 
                $('.loadingBar').css({display:'block'});

                //send the ajax request  
                $.get('contact_mail.php',{name:$('#name').val(), email:$('#email').val(), message:$('#message').val()},

                //return the data
                function(){
                    //hide the graphic
                    $('.loadingBar').css({display:'none'}); 
                    $('aside').append('<span>Merci pour votre mail, vous recevrez une réponse au plus vite.</span>');  
                }); 

                //stay on the page                  
                return false;   
            });


        }, timeToLoadWaypoint);

    }

        //if url 

        if(!window.location.hash){
            // animation d'entrée
            var $blackLine = $('.black-line');
            var $header = $('header');
            var $frontContainer = $('.front #container');

            $blackLine.css('left','-500px');
            $frontContainer.css('top','-1000px');
            $('.front .hideNavigation, header nav').hide();

            $('header h1, section h1, article').css({'z-index':'-1','left':'-1000px'});
            $header.css('background-image','url(img/headerBack41.png)');

            $('.header2').css({'top':'-1000px', 'left':'500px'}).show();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $frontContainer.animate({'top':'0'}, 400, 'easeOutCirc');
                $('.header2').animate({'top':'0', 'left':'0'}, 600);
            }, 1300);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.front .hideNavigation, header nav').fadeIn(1200);
                $('section h1').animate({'left':'0'}, 700);
                $('article').animate({'left':'0'}, 800);
                $blackLine.animate({'left':'798px'}, 700);
                $('.black-line.bl2').animate({'left':'787px'}, 600);
                $('.black-line.bl2.bl3').animate({'left':'776px'}, 700);
                $header.find('h1').css({'z-index':'10','left':'940px', 'opacity': '0'});
                $header.css('background-image','url(img/headerBack.png)');
                $('.header2').fadeOut(100);
            }, 1900);
        }

    //chargement du projet en temps normal
    $('header nav a, .arrow').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(clickLinkAllow === 1){
            clickLinkAllow = 0;

            $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);

            var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' article, .arrow';

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.load').html('loading...')
                    .css({'top':'-1000px', 'left':'490px' , 'opacity':'0'})
                    .load(url, function(){
                        $('.description').hide();
                        $('.arrow').hide();
                    });
            }, 750);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.load').animate({'top':'0', 'left':'0' , 'opacity':'1'}, 1000);
            }, 1300);

            $('header nav a').removeAttr('rel');            
            var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            $('header nav a[href^='+ hash +']').attr('rel', 'active');      

            afterload(2000);
        }

    });

    //bbq plugin
    var clicked = 0;

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var $body = $('body');

    $('header nav a, .arrow').live('click', function(){
        clicked = 1
    });
        if(clicked === 1){
            clicked = 0;
        } else {

            //credit http://emanuelfelipe.net/themeforest/ajax-portfolio/

            var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            var href = $('header nav a').each(function(){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
                    var toLoad = hash+'.html article, .arrow';
                    var $header = $('header');

                    $('.load').css({'top':'0', 'left':'0' , 'opacity':'1'}).load(toLoad, function(){
                        afterload(200);     
                    });

                    $keyboardUse.addClass('full').show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $keyboardUse.removeClass('full');
                    }, 10000);

                    $header.css('background-image','url(img/headerBack.png)');
                    $('.header2').hide();

                    $header.find('h1').css('z-index','999');
                    keyboardUseShowFirst = 1;
                }

            });

            $('header nav a').removeAttr('rel');
            $('header nav a[href^='+ hash +']').attr('rel', 'active');


            $body.css('overflow-y','hidden');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $body.css('overflow-y','scroll');
            }, 2000);
        }
    });

        $(window).trigger("hashchange");

});
```

You can find it also here : http://jsfiddle.net/BXcHS/3/

This website is for my last exam in one week and I don't know what to do because it works perfectly on firefox and quite well with Opera.

Comment: Google Chrome team would rather fix bugs than increase program version :)

Comment: Yes I know but maybe somebody would know how to fix or improve performance with my code. I don't know what to do..

Comment: i'm going to optimize with [link](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx) then I'll come back..

Comment: Is GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D enabled in chrome://flags ? Try disabling it? I imagine Chrome bug #82559 is the culprit. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82559

Comment: @chris I never activate this so I think it's not that but thank you.

Comment: Finally I find the problem. I optimized my javascript but it's was mainly due to css3 like css-shape and css-rotation. I disable both and now it work quite well !